# tflite merging models and conditional prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I have a question and I wish you can have some answers or proposition. How can I merge three CNN models into one single model using conditions on the prediction of the first two models in tflite ?

I try first to explain my actual solution and the steps I implemented.

The idea is that I have trained three different models to distinguish 4 final classes, the first two models predict 2 outputs (One final classe (fc) and One Sub-classe (sc)), the third model predicts 2 final classes.

I have trained the three models separately, they have the same architecture but different datasets. the 3 datasets contain the same images but are differently organised according to the belonging of the final classes to subclasses. This solution gives me a better testing result of 89% compared to a single model which gives 74%. That's why I want to keep the three models and make a conditional combination.

Now I'am using a class that, loads a tflit model, loads the image, performs the prediction, and classify the image. As follows:

```
class model1_model2_model3_pipline:
  def __init__(self,model_path):
    self.load_model(model_path)

  def load_model(self,model_path):    
    self.tflite_interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
    self.tflite_interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    self.input_details = self.tflite_interpreter.get_input_details()
    self.output_details = self.tflite_interpreter.get_output_details()
    self.d, self.w, self.h, self.ch = self.input_details[0]['shape'] 

  def load_image(self,image_path):
    imarray = cv2.imread(f'{image_path}')
    image = cv2.cvtColor(imarray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (self.h, self.w))
    image = np.expand_dims(image, 2)
    image = np.array(image,  dtype=self.input_details[0]['dtype'])
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return image

  def mpredict(self,image):     
    tflite_interpreter = self.tflite_interpreter
    tflite_interpreter.set_tensor(self.input_details[0]['index'], image)
    st = time.time()
    tflite_interpreter.invoke()
    elp = time.time() - st
    return elp

  def classify_image(self, top_k=1):
    output_details = self.output_details[0]
    output = np.squeeze(self.tflite_interpreter.get_tensor(output_details['index']))
    if output_details['dtype'] == np.uint8:
      scale, zero_point = output_details['quantization']
      output = scale * (output - zero_point)
    ordered = np.argpartition(-output, top_k)
    return [(i, output[i]) for i in ordered[:top_k]]

  def predict_single_image(self,image_path):
    img = self.load_image2(image_path)
    self.mpredict(img)
    out = self.classify_image(top_k=1)
    return out
```

Now I have to make three instances of the class and perform prediction with defining conditions for each model prediction.

```
# fc: final-class, sc: sub-class
MAP_CHARACTERS_model1 = {
  0: 'fc1',
  1: 'sc1',
  }
MAP_CHARACTERS_model2 = {
  0: 'fc2',
  1: 'sc2',
  }

MAP_CHARACTERS_model3 = {
  0: 'fc3',
  1: 'fc4',
  }

x_model1 = model1_model2_model3_pipline(model1_pth) #pth for path
x_model2 = model1_model2_model3_pipline(model2_pth)
x_model3 = model1_model2_model3_pipline(model3_pth)

out_model1 = x_model1.predict_single_image(im_pth)
predicted = MAP_CHARACTERS_model1[out_model1[0][0]]

if predicted == 'sc1':
  out_model2 = x_model2.predict_single_image(im_pth)
  predicted = MAP_CHARACTERS_model2[out_model2[0][0]]
  if predicted =='sc2':
    out_model3 = x_model3.predict_single_image(im_pth)
    predicted = MAP_CHARACTERS_model3[out_model3[0][0]]
```

I want to merge these three models into one single model and perform the prediction at only one step. Is there a solution to do this process on tflite ?

Answer (score 0):

The easy/recommended way is to add the extra conditioning in TF. This will get you one big model in TF that does what you want, then convert this merged model to TFLite.